# How remove css from body after popup modal closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am beginner in web development.

I have a modal show and close

To my close popup modal function, I need add remove this style:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none;  }
html, body { -ms-overflow-style: none; overflow: auto; }
```

How can I make it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // show 
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      // $('#modal__trigger2').trigger('click');
      $('#demoModal').modal('show');
    }, 2000);

  // and close
  $('.close-modal-box').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#demoModal').modal('hide');
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

html,
body {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why? Can't you just leave it

Comment: I have problem with animation. When website is load - i need hide scroll. After close popup i want show it :)

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with frameworks and HTML. Click edit, scroll down and click edit above snippet. This sounds like an X/Y problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your styles in a class like this:

```css
.modal-open {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
}
.modal-open::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none;  }
```

and then your js code would look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // show 
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
      $('#demoModal').modal('show');
    }, 2000);

  // and close
  $('.close-modal-box').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#demoModal').modal('hide');
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
    document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
  });
});
```

Comment: You want the body to have no scroll when the modal is open, right?

Comment: There is only one scrollbar for the modal itself. The scrollbar of the content behind isn't visible because bootstraps modal use `modal-open` class to the `body` which has `overflow: hidden;`. @traffske The example of Al-Mootasem Bellah does what you have asked.

Comment: @Nasa Why aren't you using jQuery like that `$('body').removeClass('modal-open');` or correct duplicates in the function like the `scrollTop` ?

Comment: @UfguFugullu, your point about bootstrap hiding the body's overflow is indeed correct which confused me because that is what traffske is doing in his question.. why am I not using jQuery? Idk..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `show.bs.modal` and `hide.bs.modal` events, raised by the modal, to attach code before showing and before hiding the modal. (Or the `shown.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.mdoal` events for when the modal is completly shown/hidden).

For Example:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
  // Here you can do stuff when the modal is getting opened
});

$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
  // Here you can do stuff when the modal is getting closed
});
```